# Seperate ALL caps from query when appears after lowercase word

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run a select query (sql) that will search a column in a table and return only the words that are in all caps when the words in all caps follow a word that contains a number or lower case letters. The string is not going to be the same everytime. examples are

1. Taliban Revival 14 TRILITERAL/YALE PB (+CL,TRD) *row1
2. ABBATE: History of Opera 12 NORTON (TRD)  *row3
3. ACEVES: Nine Seasons 12 INDIGENOUS PB (TRD) *row3

   - in row1 i would need TRILITERAL/YALE PB
   - in row2 i would need NORTON (TRD)
   - in row3 i would need WATERBURY PB  (ABBEY)

as seen in the examples above sometimes the string starts with all caps but that is not the term i need i need the term after lower case (always at the end)

thanks for the help

Comment: You will probably have to define your own function to do this.

Comment: Fix your example and redefine your logic, it is not clear what you are doing with text in brackets

Comment: i need the term after lower case (always at the end) that is in all caps so it would be something like everything to the right of the lowercase